# Нету доступа после закрытия файла

Tags: c, файлы, c++

Всем привет. Использую в проекте запись в бинарный файл с помощью функций fwrite, fopen, fclose. Иногда (примерно каждый 10-20 файл), происходит ошибка доступа к файлу, т.е. "файл используется другим приложением" (т.е. моим), при этом в консоле я вижу, что fclose выполнена успешно. В чем может быть проблема? Программа многопоточная, имя файла передается в другой поток, после успешеного fclose, но другой поток не может с ним работать.

Comment: Для синхронизации использую бустовский mutex, оба потока блокирую с помощью scoped_lock. Поток обрабатывает файл, только после отработки fclose, исключено, что он пытается обработать файл, во время записи в него.

Comment: @n1n1n1, винда, буст, потоки и stdio. Гремучая смесь. 

Может где-то иногда еще и [dup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms235445%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) вызываете?

А в принципе,  виндовым юзерам хватает уже написанных глюков.

Comment: @avp, чем Вам все это не угодило? Boost - с ним удобно создавать и контролировать потоки, а stdio выбран в первую очередь из-за скорости работы с данными, посмотрите сравнение с fsteam'ом и вопросы отпадут. Не думаю, что использование *nix, привело бы решению. Dup не используется, только fopen, fwrite, fclose.

Comment: @n1n1n1, из всего, что Вы используете мне нравится только `stdio` (и то в \*nix).

Все остальное слишком непредсказуемо.

--

Я прочитал Ваши комментарии. Видимо к винде Вы крепко привязаны сторонним разработчиком .dll, поэтому вопрос о работоспособности в \*nix не актуален.

А зачем Вам потоки и вся связанная с ними головная боль, если речь идет нее о микросекундах, а о **секундах???**

Естественно, мне не известны детали взаимодействия этих потоков, но IMHO просто 2 процесса, связанные пайпом были бы более надежным решением (даже в творении имени Б.Гейтса).

Comment: @avp, потоки нужны, один поток собирает данные с датчиков, второй обрабатывает данные. Записываю данные, которые насобирал (не все). Потом я это дело архивирую и удаляю исходный файл. Проблема проявляется в том, что я не могу удалить файл (DeleteFile или в ручную через проводник). На данный момент я сел переписывать все приложение, по результатам отпишусь.

Comment: @n1n1n1, Вам, конечно, виднее. Только из первого описания (2 потока, один передает во второй через очередь имя файла) этого не следует.

Точно также могут быть 2 процесса и один передает второму имя файла через pipe.

Типичный конвейер. Элементарно реализуется, используя POSIX `popen()`. 
Даже детали работы с процессами не надо обдумывать.

А вот второй комментарий лично меня несколько запутал. Кто все-таки в файл пишет и делает `fclose()`, а кто удалить этот файл не может?

Или участников вообще не двое?

Comment: @avp, проблема была в том, что dll не закрывала за собой файл. Один поток собирает данные, второй обрабатывает. Спасибо всем за помощь.

Answer (score 3):

Файловая подсистема - асинхронная. И если один поток закрыл файл, это не значит, что файл уже физически закрыт и другой поток сможет его закрыть. Самый простой вариант - это сделать умное открытие. Если файл не удалось открыть, то делаем задержку на 100-200 мс и пытаемся снова. Если после 10 попыток открыть не удалось - значит файл открыть нельзя. Задержу и повторы выбираем эмпирическим путем. Плюс ко всему, можно вести список последних закрытых файлов (и время последнего открытия). Если файл был закрыт в последние две-три минуты, то стоит пытаться повторять. Если файл был закрыт давно (опять же, подбираем экспериментально), то много раз пытаться повторять не нужно. Нет смысла.

Comment: Файл открывается, только после успешного закрытия, иначе он не обрабатывается.

Comment: я верю Вам. Но то, что dll гарантированно закрыла файл с соблюдением всех ритуалов, абсолютно не значит, что Вы его можете уже открыть. Но через 0.1 секунды скорее всего да.
Я сам на подобное попадал и не один раз. Только у меня был немножко другой случай. Один поток писал в файл лог и по завершению закрывал его. Другой тред отслеживал зависшие потоки и пытался подчистить за ними, в том числе проанализировать и удалить лог файл. И хотя по глобальному логу было видно, как посылается сигнал потоку, тот закрывает файл, завершает работу, а основной не может получить доступ к лог файлу.

Comment: @KoVadim, интересная информация. 

Как думаете, для разных *процессов* это так же?

Вообще-то я провел маленький эксперимент (один поток, один процесс)

     if (!(f1 = fopen("123.txt", "wb+"))) {
       perror("f1");
       exit (1);
     }
     if (!(f2 = fopen("123.txt", "wb+"))) {
       perror("f2");
       exit (1);
     }
     fprintf (f1, " go %d f1 ", getpid()); fflush(f1);
     getchar(); 
     for (... и т.д.

ничто им не помешало писать в один и тот же файл (поверх друг-друга, конечно), даже одновременно из разных окошек (cmd).

Comment: даже не знаю, нужно попробовать будет повторить. Но тут сложно говорить о 100% повторяемости.

Answer (score 0):

Если есть потоки, нужна синхронизация. В винде это критические секции, мьютексы, семафоры или на худой конец сишный flock.  Да и зачем закрывать файл, почему бы не сделать что-то вида:

fopen - открыли файл, передали хендл потокам.

Процедура потока:
синхронизация (критическая секция например)
пишем в файл
конец синхронизации (тут другой поток получает доступ к файлу и все сначала).

При завершении процесса вызываем fclose.

Comment: Не получится передать handle. Файл отдается на обработку dll, которая принимает полный путь на файл. Сослаться на dll не могу, так как сам пытался удалить файл из под проводника, и он выдал ошибку, что невозможно удалить файл, так как занят моим приложением.

Comment: Так. ТС начинает колоться. Уже выплыло, что речь идёт о виндах. Немного погодя, возможно, сообщит, что это за dll (там вроде масса вариантов, включая inproc com-сервер)...

Comment: dll написана сторонним разработчиком, так что подробностей дать не могу, кроме того, что там 1 голая функция со строкой на входе.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, вы не используете правильную синхронизацию? Например, вы забыли использовать `CRITICAL_SECTION`?

Функция `fclose` должна быть синхронной, в [`документации`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxfsw25t.aspx) и [остальном интернете](https://www.google.com/search?q=is+fclose+synchronous) нет никаких указаний на асинхронную природу `fclose`. Так что проблема должна быть именно в многопоточности.

Comment: Другой поток получает имя файла, только после успешного fclose, это 100%. У меня сделано так: два потока, 1 общий mutex и очередь, которая блокируется этим мьютексом. Первый поток, собирает данные, после успешного сбора, блокирует очередь и сует туда имя файла. Второй поток, либо спит, либо обрабатывает файл (т.е. передает dll имя файла) указанный в очереди. Имя файла генерируется с точностью до секунды, а время сбора информации около 2-5 минут.

Comment: @n1n1n1: Попробуйте следующее:

1. Попытайтесь воспроизвести проблему на тестовой программе _без_ потоков. Если воспроизведётся, мы исключили одного «подозреваемого».
2. Если тестовая программа работает, опубликуйте код, обеспечивающий многопоточность, так как проблема методом исключения в нём.